# mysql statmet that match exaxct "1" using regex

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, database

I want to create a regex to find a single 1 from the flowing

the following list is the sample of the column value I like to search in

- **1**,2
- 2,**1**
- 3,**1**,2
- 7,171,818
- 71,17,11
- **1**

Note: the needed match is bolded in the prev list

Comment: I think you have quite good chances that you will be able to if you really want to!

Comment: fairly simple `[^\d](1)[^\d]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with either approach ...

```
SELECT data FROM SAMPLE
WHERE data REGEXP '^1,|,1$|,1,|^1$'
```

[image]

```
SELECT * 
FROM sample
WHERE 
(data LIKE '1,%'
 OR
data LIKE '%,1'
 OR
data LIKE '%,1,%'
 OR
data LIKE '1')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is another option:

```
\b1\b
```

It matches the "word" "1".

DETAIL:

From the "re_format" manual:

> `\b` Matches the null string at a word boundary (either the beginning or the end of the word).

Here it is used with grep:

```
$ grep -e "\b1\b" text5
1,2
2,1
3,1,2
1
```

The file "text5" has the lines from your question:

```
$ cat text5
1,2
2,1
3,1,2
7,171,818
71,17,11
1
```

Comment: Only in some regexp engines is `\b` implemented; not MySQL's.  Instead, use `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` for start and end of "word", respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with regexps, simply do:

```
WHERE find_in_set('1', col)
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Easier to read than

```
WHERE col REGEXP "[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]"
```

Answer (score 0):

[^\d]1,|,1[^\d]|^1|1$

this one worked fine